# How to struture the following data with duplicate keys in java

Tags: java, arrays

Can anyone provide me the idea, what data structure should i use to for the following data structure :

Data is in following format :

```
+--------+---------+
|Type    | Number  |
+--------+---------+
|Mailbox | 101     |
|Mailbox | 102     |
|Mailbox | 101     |
|Mailbox | 102     | 
+------------------+
```

You can see that Type is duplicate and Number is also duplicate. But i want to store values in list or map so that only it contains elements having duplicate **Mailbox** value but not having duplicate **Number** values.

i.e. Type column can have duplicate value but Number column does not contain duplicate values. See below :

```
+--------+---------+
|Type    | Number  |
+--------+---------+
|Mailbox | 101     |
|Mailbox | 102     |   
+------------------+
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Note :- I am reading the data from .csv file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Map<String, Set<Integer>>`.

In your case, you would get: `"Mailbox" -> {101, 102}`

Example:

```
Map<String, Set<Integer>> map = new HashMap<String, Set<Integer>>();
// + some for loop here
Set<Integer> ints = map.get(type);
if(ints == null) {
    ints = new HashSet<>();
    map.put(type, ints);
}
ints.add(intToAdd);
```

Comment: @Vakh +1 for you.. I also want to add the ints values in sorted order. Should i use sortedset in that case ...

Comment: Use ``TreeSet`` instead of ``HashSet``.

Answer (score 0):

Store the values in a `HashMap<Integer, String>`. `HashMap` does not allow duplicate keys.

**Example for some of my more trigger happy amigos**

```
Map<Integer, String> values = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

values.put(105, "Mailbox");

values.put(199, "Mailbox");

System.out.println("Key = 105, Value = " + values.get(105));

// Outputs Key = 105, Value = Mailbox.
```

Comment: Lol, he wants structure that allows duplicate key-value pairs and not that.

Comment: Hence why I'm mapping the `Integer` to the `Type`, and not the other way around. "Lol".

Comment: @Ragnar Not so fast, he maps it the other way around, values can be duplicated of course. But then again it is not mentioned if there can exist the same Number of a different Type, in which case this is not ideal either.

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers author did not tell us what will be key and what will be value so it's hard to say what will be right structure.

Comment: Although it should have been obvious from the Object declaration that I was mapping `Integer` to `String`, and if you had read the question properly you would know that `String` can be duplicated, `Integer` can not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Map to store the values . You can `NUMBER` as key and `TYPE` as value. And type of MAP you are going to use depends on the operations you perform

Check this out [Performance comparison between collections](http://java-performance.info/memory-consumption-of-java-data-types-2/)

Hope this helps !!

Answer (score 0):

Create class for storing pair:

```
class Pair {
    String type;
    int number;
}
```

and introduce there `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods:

```
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Pair pair = (Pair) o;

        if (number != pair.number) return false;
        if (type != null ? !type.equals(pair.type) : pair.type != null) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = type != null ? type.hashCode() : 0;
        result = 31 * result + number;
        return result;
    }
```

Then store this structure in simple `Set<Pair> set = new HashSet<>();`